# Npm install loads material 2.0.0-beta.3 instead of material 2.0.0-beta.2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Npm install seems to load the material 2.0.0-beta3 instead of beta.2.  The Beta3 has angular4 dependency which is an issue since I am using angular2.

package.json is as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    ....
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    ...
}
```

To check versions, I use this command:
    ng --version

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
node: 6.10.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.0.3
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.3
```

Is there another place that controls the packages other than package.json?

Comment: You can also just upgrade your dependencies to angular4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna using beta 2, just remove `^` before version of material.

then remove node_modules and install again

Comment: Yes, that was my issue.  Works as expected now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular 4.0 and above

```
  "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
```

requires a peer of angular 2.3.0. 
Because of the mismatch in the  peer dependency it installs

```
  "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
```

[image]

Also as said below in another answer you are using `^` symbol which installs the latest version. Even if you install it the peer dependency will still exists